# Flowable concat source1 and source2 to return source2 if the source1 is not avilable

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java2

I am trying to test the following case
get data from local where if it is not available then Query from the network.

my test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void getProfile_repositoryCachesAfterFirstSubscription_whenProfileAvailableInRemoteStorage() {


    // Given that the local data source has data available
    setProfileAvailable(profileRemoteDataSource, PROFILE);
    // And the remote data source does not have any data available
    setProfileNotAvailable(profileLocalDataSource);

    // When two subscriptions are set
    TestSubscriber<Optional<Profile>> testSubscriber1 = new TestSubscriber<>();
    profileRepository.getProfile().subscribe(testSubscriber1);

    TestSubscriber<Optional<Profile>> testSubscriber2 = new TestSubscriber<>();
    profileRepository.getProfile().subscribe(testSubscriber2);

    // Then profile were only requested once from remote and local sources
    verify(profileRemoteDataSource).getProfile();
    verify(profileLocalDataSource).getProfile();

    assertFalse(profileRepository.cacheIsDirty);
    testSubscriber1.assertValue(PROFILE);
    testSubscriber2.assertValue(PROFILE);
}

private void setProfileNotAvailable(ProfileDataSource dataSource) {
    when(dataSource.getProfile()).thenReturn(Flowable.just(Optional.absent()));

}

private void setProfileAvailable(ProfileDataSource dataSource, Optional<Profile> profile) {
    // don't allow the data sources to complete.
    when(dataSource.getProfile()).thenReturn(Flowable.just(profile).concatWith(Flowable.never()));

}
```

and here is my repository

```
public Flowable<Optional<Profile>> getProfile() {
        Flowable<Optional<Profile>> localTask = localDataSource
                .getProfile()
                .doOnNext(singleData -> {
                    if (singleData.isPresent()) {
                        Profile profile = singleData.get();
                        saveSingleDataInToCash(profile);
                    }
                })
                .firstElement().toFlowable();
        Flowable<Optional<Profile>> remoteTask = remoteDataSource.getProfile()
                .doOnNext(singleData -> {
                    if (singleData.isPresent()) {
                        Profile profile = singleData.get();
                        saveProfile(profile);
                    }
                });
// Query the local storage if available. If not, query the network.

        return Flowable.concat(localTask, remoteTask)
                .firstElement()
                .toFlowable();

}
```

the problem is when

```
// Query the local storage if available. If not, query the network.
     Flowable.concat(localTask, remoteTask)
                        .firstElement()
                        .toFlowable();
```

is called I get an error
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
profileRemoteDataSource.getProfile();

but if I change .firstElement() to  .elementAt(1) it works fine,

so what am I missing here?
the expected behaviour is when the local return absent it should retun from the network.